# import pynput only works in IDLE Shell and doesn't work in a script

Tags: python, pynput

I've recently has this error where when I use pynput in the IDLE shell, it works fine. But if I open a file and use it as a script I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Abdou/Python/Test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pynput
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import keyboard
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    backend = backend(__name__)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 76, in backend
    raise ImportError('this platform is not supported: {}'.format(
ImportError
```

The main thing I can deduct from this is that its an import error and that the platform is not supported. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: I downgraded my pynput to an earlier version to see if my platform didn't support that version of pynput. Now I get a different error message which says:
```
ImportError: Module use of python36.dll conflicts with this version of Python.
```

Help will really be appreciated :)

Comment: Are you working on Windows?

Comment: Yes. I am working on windows.

Comment: That's quite strange, I suppose you post an issue on [Github](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput)

Comment: I just today had an exactly the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04.3 and with Python 3.10.12. Yesterday evening it worked. Only thing that changed after yesterday was that I shut off and switched on my computer and did the ordinary apt-update and apt-upgrade :(